# How can I implement zero-shot classification using MindsDB and MQL (for my MongoDB instance)?

Tags: mongodb, machine-learning, nlp, mindsdb

I am using [MindsDB](https://github.com/mindsdb/mindsdb) to do a zero-shot classification using the `facebook/bart-large-mnli` model and the web store data I have in a MongoDB instance. MindsDB documentation only explains how to achieve this using SQL, but I would like to achieve this using MQL for my MongoDB instance.

Here is the doc on how to achieve zero-shot classification using SQL.

```sql
CREATE MODEL mindsdb.hf_zs_bart
PREDICT PRED
USING
 engine = 'huggingface',
 task = 'zero-shot-classification',
 model_name = 'facebook/bart-large-mnli',
 input_column = 'text',
 candidate_labels = ['Books', 'Household', 'Clothing & Accessories', 'Electronics'];
```

But as this is for SQL, MongoDB Compass will throw a parsing error. Has anyone else tried achieving this using MQL? Should I use SQL and switch to MQL to achieve this?

Comment: @ray That article is quite outdated. There is a new syntax supported by MindsDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MindsDB just released a new version of the docs that contains the Mongo Query Language examples. To use the zero-shot classification you will need to provide **task**  and **candidate_labels**  in the model training_parameters  as:

```
db.models.insertOne({
    name: 'my_model_name',
    predict: 'pred',
    training_options: {
        engine: 'zero-shot-classification',
        task: 'text-classification',
        model_name: 'facebook/bart-large-mnli',
        input_column: 'text',
        candidate_labels: ['Books','Household','Clothes']
      }
})
```

For more information and the supported mongo syntax, you can check the new [NLP Mongo docs](https://docs.mindsdb.com/using-mongo-api/nlp)